# How to prove that the potential of a conservative central force depends only on the magnitude of the distance & not on the direction of the vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, conservative-field

If a conservative [central force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force) acts on a body then its potential only depends on the magnitude of the distance between two bodies (does not depend on direction of vector). Is there any proof of it and is this only the case of central force?

Answer (score 1):

If the force is conservative then it is the gradient of the potential:

$$ \mathbf F = -\nabla \mathbf V $$

If we write this out in component form (in polar coordinates) we get:

$$\begin{align}
F_r &= \frac{d\mathbf V}{dr} \\
F_\theta &= \frac{d\mathbf V}{d\theta} \\
F_\phi &= \frac{d\mathbf V}{d\phi}
\end{align}$$

Since we are told that the force is central that means $F_\theta = F_\phi = 0$, which means $dV/d\theta = dV/d\phi = 0$ and therefore the potential depends only on $r$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic fact for telling this is that **central forces are conservative in nature**. This means the work done by a conservative force between any two points is independent of the path, but depends only on the initial and final points only. In such a case, the work done by a conservative force in traversing from point $a$ to point $b$ is given by:

$$W=-\int_{r_a}^{r_b}\vec{F}.d{\vec{r}}=-\int_{r_b}^{r_a}\vec{F}.d{\vec{r}}$$

This implies
$$W_c=\int_{r_a}^{r_b}\vec{F}.d{\vec{r}}+\int_{r_b}^{r_a}\vec{F}.d{\vec{r}}=0$$

where $W_c$ represents the work done by a conservative force around any closed path. So we write

$$\oint\vec{F}.d\vec{r}=0\Rightarrow \nabla \times\vec{F}=0\space \space \text{(by Stoke's theorem)}$$

This means the vector or **our conservative force is irrotational**. **Hence it can be represented as the gradient of a scalar potential** (since the curl of the gradient of a scalar function is zero).

Hence we write

$$\vec{F}=-\nabla\phi$$

where $\phi$ is the scalar potential.

Examples for conservative forces include central forces like electrostatic forces, gravitational forces etc. The principle that we used here: If a vector is irrotational, then it can be represented as the gradient of a scalar potential is a basic theorem of vector calculus, which can be easily proved.

Now, as you can see we derived the potential of a conservative (central) force. This scalar potential depends only on the magnitude of the vector, not on the direction. Because our conservative force is a vector quantity, it has both magnitude and direction. But the value of scalar potential (that has no direction) depends only on the magnitude of the force. The scalar potential is given by

$$\phi=-\int_0^r \vec{F}.d{\vec{r}}$$

Suppose I define the force as $\vec{F}=F_x\hat{x}+F_y\hat{y}+F_z\hat{z}$ and $\vec{r}$ is nothing but the position vector given by $\vec{r}=dx\hat{x}+dy\hat{y}+dz\hat{z}$. Hence the integral becomes:

$$\phi=-\int_0^r (F_x\hat{x}+F_y\hat{y}+F_z\hat{z}).(x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z})=-\int_0^r (F_xdx+F_ydy+F_zdz)$$

From this, it is clear that the scalar potential depends only on the magnitude of the force in all directions ($F_x$, $F_y$, $F_z$), not on the directive property of the vector.